# how can i generate a form contaning all field from a excel sheet in php

Tags: php

Hi I have a excelsheet contaning column name and salary with multiple data  now I want to generate a form contaning these field from excel sheet respective to each rows. please help me how can I do this in php.I do not want to use mysql for this.please help.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you need to be able to read the Excel data. Which version of Excel? xls or xlsx?
I'd suggest using the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) library for this, although there are alternatives.

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

will give you the worksheet data in a standard PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to use csv files, you can use 
fgetcsv and fputcsv : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php

check this sample.

```
<?php

define('INPUT_FILENAME', '/path/to/your/csv/file');

define('OUTPUT_FILENAME', '/path/to/your/csv/file');
define('SEPARATOR', ',');
define('ENCLOSURE', '"');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['entries'])) {
        $entries = $_POST['entries'];
    }

    // do the validation stuff here ...

    if ($ok) {
        // save the entries into the DESTINATION file

        $handle = fopen(OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'w');

        foreach ($entries as $entry) {
            $fields = array(
                $entry['name'],
                $entry['salary']
            );
            fputcsv($handle, $fields, SEPARATOR, ENCLOSURE);
        }

        exit('done');
    }
}

if (!isset($entries)) {
    // fetch the entries
    $entries = array();
    if (($handle = fopen(INPUT_FILENAME, 'r')) !== false) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, SEPARATOR, ENCLOSURE)) !== false) {
            list($name, $salary) = $row;
            $entries[] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'salary' => $salary
            );
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

// display the form

print '<form action="#" method="post">';

foreach ($entries as $i => $entry) {
    print '<fieldset>';
    print '<label>Name';
    printf('<input type="text" name="entries[%s]name" value="%s" />', $i, htmlspecialchars($entry['name']));
    print '</label>';
    print '<label>Name';
    printf('<input type="text" name="entries[%s]salary" value="%s" />', $i, htmlspecialchars($entry['salary']));
    print '</label>';
    print '</fieldset>';
}
print '<input type="submit" />';
print '</form>';
```

And one form per entry :

```
<?php

define('INPUT_FILENAME', '/path/to/your/csv/file');

define('OUTPUT_FILENAME', '/path/to/your/csv/file');
define('SEPARATOR', ',');
define('ENCLOSURE', '"');

$entries = array();

// Allways prefetch entries
if (($handle = fopen(INPUT_FILENAME, 'r')) !== false) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, SEPARATOR, ENCLOSURE)) !== false) {
        list($name, $salary) = $row;
        $entries[] = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'salary' => $salary
        );
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $position = null;
    if (isset($_POST['position'])) {
        $position = (int) $_POST['position'];
    }

    $name = null;
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }

    $salary = null;
    if (isset($_POST['salary'])) {
        $salary = $_POST['salary'];
    }


    // do the validation stuff here ...

    if ($ok) {
        // merge the entry into the list
        $entries[$position] = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'salary' => $salary
        );

        // save the entries into the DESTINATION file

        $handle = fopen(OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'w');

        foreach ($entries as $entry) {
            $fields = array(
                $entry['name'],
                $entry['salary']
            );
            fputcsv($handle, $fields, SEPARATOR, ENCLOSURE);
        }

        exit('done');
    }
}

// display

foreach ($entries as $i => $entry) {
    // one form per entry
    print '<form action="#" method="post">';
    print '<fieldset>';
    print '<label>Name';
    printf('<input type="text" name="name" value="%s" />', htmlspecialchars($entry['name']));
    print '</label>';
    print '<label>Name';
    printf('<input type="text" name="salary" value="%s" />', htmlspecialchars($entry['salary']));
    print '</label>';
    printf('<input type="hidden" name="position" value="%s"', $i);
    print '</fieldset>';
    print '<input type="submit" />';
    print '</form>';
}
```

Comment: thanks dude thats great solution.onething else please if you can how can i open new form for each row.

Comment: I've added one form per entry. Check the sample over.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as a webpage and then write a little bit of PHP script in it.
If you don't want mysql, use Sqlite to store the values. Sqlite will be just like a file.